# Haskell chain of functions

Tags: haskell

I have a composition of functions, many of them operators, to raise a constant to the power of a constant minus the size of the ith set in a list. Here's my code:

```
(k^).(n-).size.(phi !!) i
```

When I tried it on a test case I got

```
<interactive>:64:16-25:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘a -> Set a0’
                with actual type ‘Set a1’
    Relevant bindings include
      it :: a -> c (bound at <interactive>:64:1)
    Possible cause: ‘phi !!’ is applied to too many arguments
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘(phi !!) 3’
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘size . (phi !!) 3’
```

However,

```
(k^)$(n-)$size$(phi !!)$i
```

works. What's wrong? Why does composition not work but application work? Also, is composing the operators in parentheses the most idiomatic way to do it? It feels weird.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much nicer to just write `k^(n - size (phi !! i))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than `f . g . h x`, you want `f . g . h $ x`: the former calls `h x` immediately and then composes that, *as a function*, with `f` and `g` The latter composes together `f`, `g`, and `h` into a new function and then calls that on `i`.

Comment: So application binds higher than `.`, which binds higher than `$`?

Comment: Application binds more tightly than anything else, and `$` binds less tightly than anything else. So `.` falls in between them, as does any other operator at all.

Comment: @RenéG, to be picky, you *could* write your own operator that binds exactly as tightly as `$` if you wanted to, but you would certainly sow confusion if you did. There is no way short of macro processing to make anything bind more tightly than function application--that's fixed deep in the syntax.

Comment: To be especially picky, they all bind less tightly than `.` used as a module separator and `{}` used in record updates, both of which are syntax and not operators... but you did say "anything else" and I've personally been confused about the precedence of record update syntax before.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can use parenthesis to group function compositions, 
`((k^).(n-).size.(phi !!)) i` should work.